# Get database server's current time

Tags: php, sql

I have a row called `last_time_online` where time is set in this format:

```
2013-03-22 01:59:02 (year-month-day hour:minute:second)
```

Now I'd like to create a function called `$getime` that gets the local server time in order to compare it with the current time. I mean something like this:

```
$sqlUpdate = "UPDATE user.user SET Online='1' WHERE id='".$_GET['char']."' AND $getime > last_time_online  LIMIT 1   ";


$getime=date('Y-d-m H:i:s') ."\n";
```

My question is that I need to add the function to the query and does not work as expected, what I want is that it gets local time and compares with the one that is in the database

Something like this:

```
local_time>database_time
```

EDIT==FIXED

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: You can't call your function `$gettime`... maybe `gettime()`. PHP time != sql time.

Comment: I understand the question but I'm not clear on comparing the local server time to the current time.  What does that mean?

Comment: `$getime > last_time_online` should read `NOW() > last_time_online`

Comment: What I want is to compare the local server time with the time that's in the database .  local_time>database_time

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the MySQL [Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html), you should have plenty of options without having to use PHP to define a variable for the query.

Answer (score 0):

Using NOW() in your mySQL query will get you the current time. I use that one when I'm sending a query from PHP (inserting data instead of using the timestamp that could update on a change to the table row) for something like CreatedDate...etc.